# SOAP UI as a server to push messages to the client connected

Tags: c++, c++11, curl, push-notification, soapui

I would like to test my web service listener class. The listener class can able to send and receive soap request and response respectively using C++11 and cURL. But My listener needs to receive push messages as well which I am not sure whether my listener able to do it or not. I have WSDL (2)files of the actual web service. Where in I have a message formats for responses.

Basically I want to configure SOAP UI which accepts connection request, if it is connected it should start pushing messages to the connected client.  Is there any possibility to implement such scenario in SOAP UI? {if there is any other ways to the implement the same also welcome}

Once I have connected with the web service the connection will left open. Whenever the service have new message, it will simply send the message to the client with out the need of any request from client. I hope now it is clear.

Comment: You should use `Mock Service` in SoapUI. Refer documentation at soapui.org. And you can also watch [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VwTOFsY4cWQ) for good start.

Comment: @Rao thanks for the response. I already know how to mock a web service in general. But I don’t find any document or tutorial which helps to push messages to the client.

Comment: Sorry did not get. What do you mean by saying push messages to the client? Please el

Comment: Please elaborate with details.

Comment: I am going to receive messages from the web service which pushes messages to me whenever it get updates form its resources. It means the connection will remains open so that it will send the messages with out any requests. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Not sure if the use case. Please note that SoapUI itself a client software .

Comment: But cant we mock that as a server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131069/discussion-between-kid-and-rao).